# WPF gif animation

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, animation

I have a following problem:
I want to load a next screen. And while next screen is loading I want to show loading animation to user. 
Its could not be done on another thread than GUI thread.
And I need to run animation at the same time. Also in a gui thread.. 
The window with animation looks like this :

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Loading"
Width="640" Height="480" Background="{x:Null}" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#4C000000">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="277" Height="277">
    <MediaElement x:Name="Loading" MediaEnded="Loading_MediaEnded" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"     
    Source="Images/Loading.gif" LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="None" Clip="M0.5,19.5 C0.5,9.0065898 9.0065898,0.5 19.5,0.5 L257.5,0.5 C267.99341,0.5 276.5,9.0065898 276.5,19.5 L276.5,257.5 C276.5,267.99341 267.99341,276.5 257.5,276.5 L19.5,276.5 C9.0065898,276.5 0.5,267.99341 0.5,257.5 z"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I create an instance of this class and call Show fuction

```
LoadingAnim loadingAnimation  = new LoadingAnim();
loadingAnimation.Owner = this;
loadingAnimation.Show();
```

and after that I want to start loading the next screen.
The problem is that animation shows up only after 6 the screen loaded

I think  that The problem is I run both of them on the gui thread. 
Anyone have an idea what should I do in this case ?

Comment: You can only do this by running your function on another thread ...

Comment: regardless to the loading indicator, any job that takes 6 seconds must be on a worker thread or the UI will hang. if for some reason you cannot do that it's a major  bug in the design ...

Comment: OK.
I want to load a next screen.
Its could not be done on another thread. Only on gui
And I need to run animation at the same time.
Also in a gui thread..

Comment: Opening another screen doesn't take 6 seconds. I'm assuming your doing some kind of initializations that take up your time. Those can probably move to a worker thread ...

Comment: the thing is, a thread can work on a single item at a given time. It could create your animation, or load/initialize your new screen. If it is initializing the new window (possibly in load event or in constructor), it will not repaint/refresh the window, causing a "hang" (ANR - application not responding, if you will). You should move one of the two jobs (preferably not the GUI stuff because it will be a cross-thread call) to another line of work by `Task.Run()`.